# Is MyBase.Finalize necessary?

Tags: vb.net, class

In one of my usercontrols which I programmed years ago, I find the line

```
Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    MyBase.Finalize()
End Sub
```

Unfortunatly I forgot to write a comment, so I don't know if I actually wrote that line for some reason, or if it had been created automatically (I think I remember that in previous versions of Visual Studio, some lines of code like "IsInitializing" were put automatically in the user code).

I would therefore like to ask if this line is necessary at all.

Comment: This is the default code being generated when you do not override it manually.

Comment: And do I still need it in my code, or can I delete it because VB.NET does that automatically?

Comment: I do believe that you can delete it with out any harm, as it is already handled automatically.

Comment: If you are not going to add anything then yes you can delete it. Read more about it here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize(v=vs.110).aspx TL;DR version -> it is the place where you dispose of unmanaged resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would delete either the entire Finalize function or leave the entire function there. The extra code will not really cause any issue. I would not delete just the MyBase.Finalize() line.  If you do not override the method, all cleanup will happen naturally.

But if you override the method and do not call it the underlying Finalize, there is the (minor) possibility of some resources not being cleaned.